# How to handle alert click where alert generated from UIWebview .?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I used this also:

```
@interface UIWebView (JavaScriptAlert)

 - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;

@end

@implementation UIWebView (JavaScriptAlert)

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    UIAlertView *dialogue = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert Title" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [dialogue show];
}
```

Comment: Can you please share code for creating Category on UIWebView

Comment: Have a look in this Category https://github.com/wangruofeng/IOS-Categories/blob/master/IOS-Categories/UIKit/UIWebView/UIWebView%2BAlert.m

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UIAlertView's delegate

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    UIAlertView *dialogue = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert Title" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    dialogue.tag = 1;
    [dialogue show];
}


-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == 1) {
         if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
             //Do something here
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display an alert in Javascript--this will look exactly like a `UIAlertView`. Then upon dismissing the alert, redirect the user to "someaction://" in Javascript. On the device, implement `UIWebViewDelegate`'s `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` like so:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if ([request.URL absolutePath] hasPrefix:@"someaction://"]) {
        // do what you want to do after the alert has been dismissed
    }

    return NO;
}
```